# Cannot use variable name inside Node.js require

Tags: node.js, react-native, require

I want to import an image into my react native app locally.

```
render() {

    console.log(this.props.image);   //   this logs '../../images/avatartest.jpg' every time

    let test = require (this.props.image!);   //    bang is required because of interface
    return (
        <ImageBackground
            source={test}
        >
        </ImageBackground>
    );
}
```

Running this code produces this error:

[image]

**Is there no way to accept a variable name that has a string?**

Comment: you added `!` in require `require (this.props.image!)`

Comment: @RahulSharma That bang is required to remove an intellisense error. It is the same error with or without it.

Answer (score 1):

All requires must be statically analyzable. That means you cannot use variables in require.

You can bundle the images in your app manually and the use where variables will work.

```
<Image source={{ uri: this.props.image }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is to dynamically import an image which is not supported, the best way to do this is to require the images beforehand and pass the required value as a prop. Assume that the parent component for your component is ImageView

```
export default const images = {
   img1:require('IMAGE_URL')
}

//import this in the your view and use it as the prop value 
<ImageView image={images.img1}></ImageView>
```

The above method will make sure that the packager can locate the image.